# web notifications in <title> from chatbox

Tags: php, javascript, notifications, title

I'm trying to put web notifications in the title/tab screen of my webpage. So whenever someone new says something and you're not on the tab, the  will give notifications that you have a new message.

Is there any simple way to go about this?
[Here's a live link of the chat](http://www.goawaymom.com/)
would i have to tamper with my post.php? or would

```
<?
session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
$text = $_POST['text']; 
$fp = fopen("log.html", 'a');
fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln'> C:\Users\<b>".$_SESSION['name']."></b> ".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."<br></div>");
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

or would i tamper with the input ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//If user submits the form
$("#submitmsg").click(function(){   
    var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
    $.post("post.php", {text: clientmsg});              
    $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
    return false;
});
```

thanks in advance for any help
!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to have a look at the JavaScript function [`setInterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp). Make this function check for updates every x ms, if it finds any updates; edit the page-title.

Something like this should do the trick, tweak to get preferred result:

```
// This function will run every ~1s
setInterval(function() {

   // Get the new data
   $.post('post.php', function(data) {

      // Handle the data
      document.title = data;

   });


}, 1000);
```

You should definitely add some error checking on the PHP-script (check if variables are set: `isset($_SESSION['value'])`), possibly at the javascript too.

Comment: hmmm this seems like what i need, however I can't seem to get it working. I'll keep trying at it.

Comment: @GirthRobertEshraghi What seems to be the problem? Any errors or such?

Comment: Oh and by the way, currently, you are writing the session data to a file named log.html. Perhaps you just want to echo the latest person to write directly instead?

Comment: whenever i implement it, it keeps a continuous loop of entering blank lines within the chat box. I know I'm not implementing it correctly, so I'll keep trying

Comment: good idea... maybe i can work on that tomorrow, for now i just want to make this dam notifications work

Answer (score 0):

see "document.title" in javascript.

```
var xarray = ['Someone Posted','Someone else posted'];
var i = 0;

function changeTitle(data){
  document.title = data;
}

function changeEvery5Seconds()
{
   i++;
   i = i%2;
   changeTitle(xarray[i]);
   setTimeout("changeEvery5Seconds();",5000);
}
changeEvery5Seconds();
```

Comment: its just a snippet of code i thought you would be interested in. NOT tested. :-) I think it will help!